# How to filter out values in Pyspark using multiple OR Condition?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to change a SQL query into Pyspark. The SQL Query looks like this. I need to set ZIPCODE='0' where the below conditions satisfies.

```
UPDATE COUNTRY_TABLE SET COUNTRY_TABLE.ZIPCODE = "0" 
WHERE (((COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="TN" Or
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="DEL" Or
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="UK" Or 
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="UP" Or 
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="HP" Or 
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="JK" Or 
(COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE)="MP") AND ((Len([ZIPCODE]))<"5"));
```

Pyspark Query i am trying to implement is

```
df=df.withColumn('ZIPCODE', F.when( (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'TN') | (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'DEL') \
| (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'UK') | (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'UP') | (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'HP')  \
| (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'JK') | (col('COUNTRY_TABLE.STATE') == 'MP') & (col('length_ZIP') < '5'), '0')
.otherwise(df.ZIPCODE))
```

In my pyspark code i have used one column as length ZIP so basically what i am doing i am taking out length of column(ZIPCODE) in a separate column 'length_ZIP' and checking with the value with that column.

```
df=df.withColumn('ZIPCODE', substring('ZIPCODE', 1,5)) -- take only first five character
df=df.withColumn('length_ZIP',length(df.ZIPCODE))
```

I am not getting my expected result. can anyone help me what i can do to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can clean up your code this way:

First, instead of creating one condition to each state by hand you can create a states list. So, if you want to add or remove any country you can easily do this by updating the list. The code becomes more readable.

```
states = ["TN", "DEL", "UK", "UP", "HP", "JK", "MP"]
```

and then:

Here you create a new column called "length_ZIP" running the pyspark's length function over the ZIPCODE column and retrieving the zipcodes lengths.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


df = df.withColumn("length_ZIP",F.length("ZIPCODE"))
```

Finally you overwrite the ZIPCODE column with the condition: if the state is in the states list AND the zipcode length is less then 5 is returned zero to the ZIPCODE column. Otherwise it return the own ZIPCODE number.

```
df = df.withColumn("ZIPCODE", F.when(F.col("state").isin(states) & (F.col('length_ZIP') < '5'), '0').otherwise(df["ZIPCODE"]))
```

I think that the main problem of your code is the logical operators precedence. In Python the "&" operator is read first in an operation when compared to "|" when the operations are in the same level.
If you do something like:

```
True | False & False #True
```

It will return True because the False & False is evaluated first (return False) and then True | False will return True

Comment: I edited the answers with more details

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are giving AND condition along with OR condition without separating them because of that you are not getting desired output

To resolve this, keep your all **OR** conditions in a Round bracket and then give the **AND** condition. It will first check all OR condition and then for that it will check AND condition and give output.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,length,when

df2 = df1.withColumn('Zipcode', when(((col('State') == 'TN') | (col('State') == 'DEL') \
| (col('State') == 'UK') | (col('State') == 'UP') | (col('State') == 'HP')  \
| (col('State') == 'JK') | (col('State') == 'MP')) & (col('length_ZIP') < 5), '0')
.otherwise(df.Zipcode))

df2.show()
```

- **Execution or Output**

[image]